# <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- active_support (LoadError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I hich to create a new rails project

I have this

```
 rene@Linux-Ubuntu:~/rails_projets$ rails new premier_app
```

:29:in `require': no such file to load -- active_support (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
    from :29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails:16:in`'

I have :> Ubuntu 11.10 ..
   ruby 1.9.2p218 ..
   rails 2.3.14 ..
   gem 1.8.17 ..
   zlib installed

When i make $  gem install rails --pre

I have this

```
   rene@Linux-Ubuntu:~/rails_projets$  gem install rails --pre
```

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

What i mist ?

Thank for help

René LeBlanc

Comment: I am confused... you have this question tagged as Rails 3 yet list `rails 2.3.14` as your Rails version. Which are you trying to do a new with?

Comment: I remove rails 2.3.14 and install Rails 3.2.3 and it's work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on rails 3.2.3 and I have fix it (on Ubuntu 11.10). Try this. 
First check which rvm gemset you are using.

```
user1$: rvm gemset list
```

this command give you list of gemsets like this

```
gemsets for ruby 1.9.3-p125 (found in user1/.rvm/...something.../ruby-1.9.3-p125)
=> rails31
```

now you know which gemset you want to use if more than one you can also delete it. Then set gemset by using

```
user1$: rvm gemset use rails31
```

and then I have tried **rails -v** and it's require error is gone! Fun!